# Repaint() does not work after adding more components to JPanel in Swing, Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am starting with Java and want to make a simple pong game to get into the ways of displaying stuff in java. I have created 2 classes that both extend JPanel and call the `repaint()` function every 16.6 milliseconds. I added both to a JPanel which I added to the frame, but only the component I added first displays.

I've tried to `revalidate()` after `repaint()` in both classes and made sure that the Timer actually works and that it's `actionPerformed()` method is actually called.

This is the main method:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
    //...
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    mainPanel.add(new Player());
    mainPanel.add(new Ball(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2 -40));

    frame.add(mainPanel);
  }
}
```

This is the important code for the classes (It's basically the same for both of them):

```
public class Player extends JPanel {

  public Player(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Main.frameWidth, Main.frameHeight));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    new Timer(1000/60, new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        update();
        repaint();
      }
    }).start();
  }
//...
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
}
```

(Of coure I left things like @Override or unneseccary functions out to shorten the code)

This code only paints the Player, altough I want it to display all the components of `mainPanel`.

This is an example that you can (hopefully) run. I had to split it up into 3 files, since I suck at anonymus classes:

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    mainPanel.add(new Player());
    mainPanel.add(new Ball());

    frame.add(mainPanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
///////
Player.java
//////
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Player extends JPanel{
  private int x = 20, y = 300, width = 20, height = 100;
  public Player(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    new Timer(1000/60, new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();
      }
    }).start();
  }


  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
}
//////
Ball.java
//////
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ball extends JPanel{
  private int x = 20, y = 300, width = 20, height = 100;
  public Ball(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    new Timer(1000/60, new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();
      }
    }).start();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do classes `Player` and `Ball` have defined preferred sizes? `JPanel` is a container and designed to size itself based on the GUI components it contains. It looks like your classes `Player` and `Ball` do not contain any GUI components, hence their size may be 0 (zero).

Comment: They do. I set them like this; ````setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));````

Comment: Then I think it would help people to help you if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I am going to edit the question once I have got one.

Comment: Okay, it's out now.

Comment: *"Okay, it's out now."* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `paintComponent()` of class `Player`, you paint the exact same `Rectangle` each time. In order to achieve animation, each time you paint the rectangle you need to change either its size or location or both. What do you expect the `Player` to do? Should it move up and down along the left edge of the window? Have you seen the lesson entitled [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which is part of *Oracle*'s **Java Tutorial**?

**EDIT**

I see now that `Player` hides `Ball`, because of the default layout manager of `JPanel`. The below code is essentially the code you posted but I set `GridLayout` as the layout manager for `mainPanel`. Also, a java source code file may contain more than one class but exactly one class must be `public`. Hence in the below code only class `Main` is `public`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        mainPanel.add(new Player());
        mainPanel.add(new Ball());
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Player extends JPanel {

    public Player() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2, false));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        new Timer(1000 / 60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(20, 100, 20, 100);
    }
}

class Ball extends JPanel {

    public Ball() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN, 2, false));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        new Timer(1000 / 60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(300, 300, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

And here is a screen capture of the GUI...

[image: Main]

Comment: I draw it using variables in my real code, but made its position fixed to save some lines. However, moving the Player wasn't the problem in the first place. The problem is, that only the first component that was added to mainPanel is painted.

Comment: Thanks, apparently Stack Overflow did not want to show me this until now (Yes, I refreshed the page from time to time ;)). However, since the ball needs to collide with the player, there is a problem: How do I make these JPanels overlap with another?

Comment: _How do I make these JPanels overlap with another?_ You don't. You need to paint both the ball and the player on the same `JPanel`. Search the Internet, there are several examples of the Pong game written in java. And the few I looked at appear to use only one `JPanel` to draw both the ball and the player.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a clean way of solving this though. This would mean, that I would have to port the Ball class over to the Player class, and do all the logic and drawing from there. Maybe I shouldn't be using JPanels to extend the classes? As I said I am a new to java, and this is the only way I know to create custom components.

Comment: Neither `Ball` nor `Player` should be components. Instead, have a single class to paint the game (`BatAndPaddleGameComponent`?) & `Ball` and `Player` should be classes that simply know how and where to paint themselves to a `Graphics` instance that is passed to them.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson and and Abra , it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that if I extend my window manually, the second JPanel shows up under the one responsible for the Player! This means that I'll need to set the Panels position somehow, right?

@Abra